# How to attach html element to table row in Element UI table

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

Hello I have a question on how to attach html element to table row in Element UI table.

```
<el-table
      :data="tableData"
      style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column
        prop="date"
        label="Date"
        width="180">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        prop="name"
        label="Name"
        width="180">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        prop="address"
        label="Address">
      </el-table-column>

// Add some other element in here like div,span,p etc...

    </el-table>
```

I want the html element to be added in each row. 
Is there a way to do that in Element UI?

Comment: So you've tried it and it doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried using the template slot-scope="scope"?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Yes buy it won't apply on every row only rendered once

Comment: @RenatoManalili template slot-scope will be rendered inside the cell. I want it to be outside of the cell after the very last position of td. example `<tr><td></td><td></td><div here></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but you can add an empty column and put the custom html in here:

```
<template>
  <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    border
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
      prop="date"
      label="Date"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="name"
      label="Name"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="address"
      label="Address">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column>
      <el-button>What every you want</el-button
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>
```

Or use slots:

```
<el-table
    :data="tableData"
    border
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
      prop="date"
      label="Date"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="name"
      label="Name"
      width="180">
      <template slot-scope="scope">
            <el-tag size="medium">{{ scope.row.name }}</el-tag>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="address"
      label="Address">
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
```